# Is it possible to install FortiClient 5.4.1 or 5.4.2 on Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: macos

I downloaded FortiClientOnlineInstaller, and ran the app inside. It says it's downloaded the app, and there's an "install" button. But clicking the button does nothing. No errors, popups, or anything else.

ETA: 5.4.2 has the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-Leave the unpacking/installation process and dialog active, even if the button doesnt work: do not close it or unmount the image.

-Open Finder, then use the Go to folder promt to go /private/var/

-Search for "fctupdate"

-When it is found, open the folder and run the forticlient.dmg from there.

I got some further errors, but the thing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

For Terminal users, here is the guide:

*As mentioned by @Almo, you should Leave the unpacking/installation process and dialog active, even if the button doesnt work: do not close it or unmount the image.*

1. run `cd /private/var/`
2. run `sudo find ./ -name "fctupdate"` to find out where it is
3. `cd` to that directory
4. run this:

```
MOUNTDIR=$(echo `hdiutil mount /path/to/FortiClient.dmg | tail -1 \
| awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}'` | xargs -0 echo) \
&& sudo installer -pkg "${MOUNTDIR}/"*.pkg -target /
```

5. Then the installer will display on screen.

These steps are also valid for installing version 5.4.2.